# Initialize List<> with Arrays.asList

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, array-initialization

Why does this work:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

but this does not:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList({"a","b","c"});
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is a short hand only available when constructing and assigning an array.

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

You can do this though:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
```

As `asList` can take "vararg" arguments.

Comment: The second code example doesn't compile in Java 8. It says "cannot convert `List` to `List<String>`"

Comment: That's no true, works fine in Java 5 to at least 11, just tested all. You've done some mistake @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft , maybe wrong import, java.awt.List or similar?

Answer (score 13):

Your question is why one works and the other does not, right?

Well, the reason is that `{"a","b","c"}` *is not a valid Java expression*, and therefore the compiler cannot accept it.

What you seem to imply with it is that you want to pass an array initializer without providing a [full array creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) (JLS 15.10).

The correct array creation expressions are, as others have pointed out:

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

As stated in [JLS 10.6 Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), or

```
String[] array = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
```

As stated in [JLS 15.10 Array Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

This second one is useful for inlining, so you could pass it instead of an array variable directly.

Since the `asList` method in `Arrays` uses variable arguments, and variable arguments expressions are mapped to arrays, you could either pass an inline array as in:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
```

Or simply pass the variable arguments that will be automatically mapped to an array:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
```

Comment: No, you can do `Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");`, which is shorter, and more similar to the OP's original question.

Comment: What Thomas said is still valid and doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: No, what he said is "You *have* to write", which is untrue, so, yes, it *does* deserve a downvote.

Comment: @TimPote OMG. What can I say ... I changed it. But you don't have to be so nit-picky

Comment: @Tomas Sorry, not trying to be nit-picky, but I don't want the OP to get the wrong understanding.  There *is* another, shorter alternative to this solution.  If nobody had said otherwise, he might have believed you.

Comment: @TimPote A downvote is still a too aggressive measure. Why didn't you just leave the comment for 10 minutes and see if Tomas corrects himself, and if he didn't, **then** downvote? That's what a cooperative mind would do on SO.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Perhaps, you're right.  Generally, I downvote anything that's patently false in some way (which this was, albeit a minor way).  Some users would have responded to a comment, but I've come across many that don't.  Just so you know, I took away my downvote as soon as he made his revision.  I don't know who still has one outstanding.

Comment: @TimPote Agreed, many don't respond, and I figured the outstanding DV wasn't yours. Also, a very short answer somehow invites a DV if not absolutely correct. Some kind of gut reaction at work there, I would guess...